# Why use flash to as content headings? Why not?

Tags: html, flash, heading

A large number of sites lately which use **Flash to replace what would be simple HTML headings (h1, h2, h3)**. Some of them do it consistently for every header.

**Why would you do this? What are the pros and cons of this?**

This seems strange to me and really inefficient, particularly since a page can have dozens of headers. I notice this because I use Flash Block (which temporarily disables Flash), so not everyone may have seen it.

Just today I landed [here](http://www.csssdll.qc.ca/nos-points-de-service/nos-clsc/clsc-de-lasalle/) with 4 flash headers. I've seen dozens of such use of Flash this week alone, and I am wondering if this has some benefits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sites do it so that they can use a particular font, which is not likely to be installed on most users' computers. That method is called [sIFR](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/archive/2004/08/sifr), or Scalable Inman Flash Replacement.

However newer browsers support newer font technologies as [WOFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format) and companies which host web fonts for you like [Fontdeck](http://fontdeck.com) and [Typekit](http://typekit.com). The advantage of them over the flash method is that it doesn't need flash, and if you don't have javascript enabled you see text in a default font. However you may have to pay the companies doing the font hosting.

Comment: Interesting. I do think it looks so different than the non-flash font in most cases and since it interrupts the background I think it look worst.... But what about the effect on SEO? Headers are supposed to be very important.

Comment: The search engine bots won't see the flash, they'll just see <h2><span class="sifr-alternate">heading</span></h2> - so the heading isn't lost to them.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Images instead of Flash. You can put the content of the image ( i.e.: "home") in the ALT and Title-tag. I don't know whether Google is already able to navigate through Flash menu's, but if it doesn't, it's far more SEO and user-friendly to use images.

**Edit:** There are scripts available which convert `<h2>` tags, for instance, to image with the font of your choice.